# Multiple Fields for Hyperlink Expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am building an expression for a hyperlink in SSRS. I can currently get it to point to the correct directory, but also need it to point to the correct file within the directory and I'm not sure how to include multiple fields. I'm sure its something simple that I'm missing. Would appreciate any help you all can provide. Code is below that gets to me to the directory, need to add code to get to the FileName which is the actual file. Thanks in advance.

```
    ="file://phpfile01/analyst/AMHPData/Exports/"&Fields!XML_EXPORT_DIRECTORY.Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add more fields to the expression with the &:

```
="file://phpfile01/analyst/AMHPData/Exports/" & Fields!XML_EXPORT_DIRECTORY.Value & "/" & Fields!FileName.Value
```

The extra slash may not be needed if it's included in your XML_EXPORT_DIRECTORY field.

If not if would be:

```
="file://phpfile01/analyst/AMHPData/Exports/" & Fields!XML_EXPORT_DIRECTORY.Value & Fields!FileName.Value
```